# Computing shortest decomposition of a permutation as product of 2-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations

For a permutation group on $n$ elements, a *transposition* (or 2-cycle), say $\begin{pmatrix} i & j \end{pmatrix}$ is defined as the permutation that swaps the elements at position $i$ and $j$, where $i, j \in \{1, \cdots, n\}$

It is known that any permutation can be decomposed into a product of transpositions. One way to do this is described in Algebra by Dummit and Foote, page 30. To be precise, the algorithm is about converting a permutation into a produce of disjoint cycles. However, converting any cycle into product of transposition is trivial because of $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_n \end{pmatrix} \cdots \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

Here's the description of the algorithm from Dummit and Foote ($\sigma$ is a permutation on $n$ elements.)

1. To start a new cycle pick the smallest element of $\{ 1, 2, \cdots n\}$ which has not yet appeared in a previous cycle - call it $a$ (if
   you are just starting, $a =  1$); begin the new  cycle: $(a$
2. Read off $\sigma(a)$ from the given description of $\sigma$--call it $b$. If $b=a$, close the cycle with a right parenthesis (without writing $b$ down); this completes a cycle--return to step 1. If $b \neq a$, write $b$ next to $a$ in this cycle $(a \ b$
3. Read off $\sigma(b)$ from the given description of $\sigma$--call it $c$. If $c = a$, close the cycle with a right parenthesis to complete the cycle--return to step 1. If $c \neq a$, write $c$ next to $b$ in this cycle $(a\ b\ c$. Repeat this step using the number $c$ as the new value of $b$ until cycle closes.

---

I was wondering if this is known to produce the shortest decomposition of a permutation?
Given any permutation, what is the shortest way to decompose the permutation as the product transpositions?

---

As a generalization of the problem, I'm particularly interested in finding the  decomposing permutations as the products of transpositions of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \end{pmatrix}$.

The context of the problem comes from [stack machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine), where a transposition of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to a $\text{swap}_i$ instruction. The problem is about optimizing for the smallest number of swaps to transform a stack.

Comment: If you allow any transposition the answer is $n-c$ where $c$ is the number of cycles (including cycles of size $1$) . The construction is the one in the book, the proof of minimality consists of looking at each transposition as an edge, and if you have less than $n-c$ edges then there are more components in the graph than cycles, which is not possible. If you only allow transpositions $(1,i)$ I'm not completely sure but I'm sure it's been studied.

Comment: Actually I now remember that if it's permutations only $(1,i)$ then it's a particular case of this problem: https://atcoder.jp/contests/arc124/editorial/2351

Comment: So basically the answer is $n - c + 2d$ where $d$ is the number of cycles  of size $>1$ that don't contain $1$.